# Is there an option to maintain factor levels when save a `stars` object to a tif file?

Tags: r, geospatial, r-stars

I have a raster in R as a `stars` object with an attribute that is a factor. When I save the raster to a tif file using `write_stars`, the factor levels are lost and only the integers are stored. I read somewhere that what I need is to create a Raster Attribute Table. Can this be done using `stars`?

Here is a reprex:

```r
library(stars)
#> Loading required package: abind
#> Loading required package: sf
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

m <- matrix(letters[1:9], nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
dim(m) <- c(x = 3, y = 3) # named dim
s <- st_as_stars(m)

s[["A1"]] <- factor(s[["A1"]])

plot(s)
```

[image]

```r
write_stars(s, "reprex.tif")
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-31 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

And this is how the legend of the tif looks in QGIS:

[image: The legend of the tif in QGIS]

Comment: I have to scratch a little deeper into `stars`, but tif.aux.xml is your [raster attrib table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/468723/r-terra-retain-labels-for-categorical-raster-after-writing), and can't think why stars and terra would approach differently. And [stars  data model](https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/articles/stars4.html).

Comment: How does the legend look when plotted in R, rather than QGIS? Sorry, stupid question as it is shown above. Why would this be an R problem?

Comment: I need to write several rasters using R that my colleagues will open in QGIS. I will explore the tif.aux.xml. Thanks for the clue.

Comment: `write_stars()` when writing to tif writes the .aux.xml sidecar file; if you read that tif back with `read_stars()` you'll see that the factor labels are still there. The problem seems lack of support in qgis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end it was not an R issue but a QGIS issue. The information is read by QGIS as it is stored in the xml:

```
<PAMDataset>
  <PAMRasterBand band="1">
    <CategoryNames>
      <Category></Category>
      <Category>a</Category>
      <Category>b</Category>
      <Category>c</Category>
      <Category>d</Category>
      <Category>e</Category>
      <Category>f</Category>
      <Category>g</Category>
      <Category>h</Category>
      <Category>i</Category>
    </CategoryNames>
  </PAMRasterBand>
</PAMDataset>
```

The only problem is that QGIS does not have support to visualize this in the legend, see this [issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/22427). Here a screenshot of this information in the properties of the raster in QGIS:

[image: screenshot of raster properties in QGIS]

Currently, it seems that the only solution is using some plugins or some workarounds with python...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have `QGIS` to test how this goes for your colleagues before you share with them, but I think I made things seem more complicated than needed in my comments. You want to look at `?terra::coltab` for 'color table',
that I take a detour through

```
s_rast = rast(s) 
plot(s_rast)
coltb = data.frame(values=1:9, col = rainbow(9, end = .9))
coltb
  values     col
1      1 #FF0000
2      2 #FFAC00
3      3 #A6FF00
4      4 #00FF06
5      5 #00FFB3
6      6 #009FFF
7      7 #0D00FF
8      8 #B900FF
9      9 #FF0099
has.colors(s_rast)
[1] FALSE
coltab(s_rast) <- coltb
plot(s_rast)
writeRaster(s_rast, 'sof77912406.tif') # this SO ? #
s_rast2 = rast('sof77912406.tif')
has.colors(s_rast2)
[1] TRUE
plot(s_rast2)
s_rast2_stars <- st_as_stars(s_rast2)
plot(s_rast2_stars)

s_rast2_stars
stars object with 2 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s):
 sof77912406.tif 
 a      :1       
 b      :1       
 c      :1       
 d      :1       
 e      :1       
 f      :1       
 (Other):3       
dimension(s):
  from to offset delta         refsys x/y
x    1  3      0     1 WGS 84 (CRS84) [x]
y    1  3      3    -1 WGS 84 (CRS84) [y]

s_rast2
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 3, 3, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 3, 0, 3  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
source      : sof77912406.tif 
color table : 1 
categories  : A1 
name        : A1 
min value   :  a 
max value   :  i

write_stars(s_rast2_stars, 'sof77912406_stars.tif')
s_rast2_stars_2 = read_stars('sof77912406_stars.tif')
plot(s_rast2_stars_2)
```

This isn't satisfactory, yet, for your purposes as I've lost the factor values associated with the plot colors in the stars object... So, deeper digging in stars, but perhaps allows you to test colors as appear in `QGIS`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm using {stars} because the rasters are the result of rasterizing 1e6 points and {stars} is twice faster than {terra} in doing so. So, I would prefer a solution not using {terra}. But `coltab` opens a new path to explore.

Comment: As a practical matter then, rasterize in stars, writeRaster( as below, and open in QGIS. Just installed it and colors and factors are there. Now I'll grab a GB back by removing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
r <- terra::rast(s)
writeRaster(r, "test.tif")
```